# mySQL TSV infile duplicate entries

Tags: mysql, batch-file, file-io, csv

New to mySQL scripting in general.

Uploading auto generated tsv files into local mySQL server with infile.  Windows Scheduler runs batch file which initiates infile upload.

Issue is everytime batch file runs infile process, the entries are duplicated in the table.

Is there a way to make them append instead of simply write?  Am I going to need a key for the entries in order for it to recognize the entries?

All help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*Am I going to need a key for the entries in order for it to recognize the entries?*" Yes.

Comment: Will that information be written in to the infile process?  Do you have a reference?

Comment: Once you have defined some identifying key and specified it as such in MySQL (i.e. specified it as your `PRIMARY KEY` or else defined a `UNIQUE KEY` constraint), then you can use the `REPLACE` or `IGNORE` keywords (as appropriate) to your `LOAD DATA` command.

Comment: Beware that if records exist in your table that might not exist in the file, they will be preserved; to delete them, you will need to perform a different operation (if all records are to be replaced, then first empty the table and then perform the `LOAD`; otherwise either add a flag column to indicate whether the record was found in the file, or else load into a temporary table first and then modify your table as required).

Comment: So I'm assuming something exists that will allow me to reference the data already located in the table, review the data from the tsv, and then determine whether or not to overwrite or ignore back on criteria I've set with [REPLACE] or [IGNORE].  Going off of [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html).

Comment: Performance wise, is it going to cause problems if the table is cleared and then reloaded every 1-2 hours with 2000+ entries?

Comment: Performance will depend on detail not known here: hardware specification, configuration settings, query load, row size... suggest you benchmark on your system and decide for yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Once you have defined some identifying key and specified it as such in
>   MySQL (i.e. specified it as your PRIMARY KEY or else defined a UNIQUE
>   KEY constraint), then you can use the REPLACE or IGNORE keywords (as
>   appropriate) to your LOAD DATA command. – eggyal 27 mins ago

Information regarding syntax of this process is located [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html).

Thanks to eggyal for the help.